# Is there an idiomatic way to achieve conditional block "pass-through"?

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, block, idioms

Is there a clean way to conditionally pass as a block as an argument to another method in Ruby?

In my Rails app I'm defining some customized ActionMailer behavior with a wrapper and I want to elegantly handle implicit (no block given) and explicit (block given) view templates.

```
class Mailer < ::ActionMailer::Base
  # ...
  def signed_mail(opts = {}, &block)
    # ...
    mail mail_opts, &(block_given? ? block : nil)
  end
end
```

**Is there a more idiomatic way to *optionally* pass the given block to `mail`?** The ternary operator provides for DRYer code than using an `if`/`else`, but still looks awkward.

Comment: What happens when you just call `mail mail_opts, block` ? even when block is nil? As mail method will look for default template with name signed_mail right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special for the case where no block was passed:

```
class Mailer < ::ActionMailer::Base
  # ...
  def signed_mail(opts = {}, &block)
    # ...
    mail mail_opts, &block
  end
end
```

If no block was given, `block` will already be nil, so this will faithfully pass along the lack of block.